# Empty Store Debug Information

Tags: magento1.9.2.4, error-log

Sometimes I receive such Store Debug Information.
URL, Error and Trace are all empty.
Any ideas what is this?

```
URL: 
IP Address: 80.000.00.000
Time: 2016-08-10 22:30:58 GMT
Error:


Trace:
```

Comment: In which file do you find those ?

Comment: I receive as email, as I set action as email in erros/local.xml